# Getting Error 605 in sybase ASE 15.0

Tags: sybase-ase15

We are getting error 605 in sybase ASE15.0

server  Error: 605, Severity: 21, State: 1

server  An attempt was made to fetch logical page '64000' from cache 'default data cache'. Page belongs to database 'testdb' (30), object '' (0), index '' (0), partition '' (1836412015) and not to database 'testdb' (30), object '' (99), index '' (0), partition '' (99).

How can we fix above error?

Answer (score 0):

605 means that you have a database corruption. This is very rare, but can be the result of -for example- hardware faults -- when combined with some back luck.
If you're lucky, the corruption is only in the in-memory copies of the pages, in which case a restart will clear it. But usually the corruption has made it to disk, which is worse. 
Since this seems to be related to object ID 99, it means an allocation page has been screwed up. If you're lucky you can get it fixed with dbcc checkalloc, but worst case, you may have to drop and recreate your database. So I would start with copying out all data from your tables, either to files or to a different database -- making a database dump (backup) won't help as it will contain the corruption as well.